# Prove or disprove $T(n) = T(\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor+1)+1=O(\log(n))$

Tags: time-complexity, asymptotics, recurrence-relation, big-o-notation

Lets define function $T(n)$ as

\begin{align*}
T(1) &= T(2) = 1\\
T(n) &= T(\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor+1)+1 \text{, where }n\ge 3.\\ 
\end{align*}

Does $T(n)=O(\log(n))$? I have no idea how to prove or disprove this, so I'll be glad for any help.

Comment: Have you tried induction over $n$? By proving $T(n) \leq c\cdot \log n$ at every step? (for some large enough $c$)

Comment: Consider $n=2^k$.

Comment: @zkutch It's a tiny bit more complicated, but not much. Consider n = 2^k + 1 instead.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/136467/prove-tn-t-left-lceil-fracn2-right-rceil-1-o-logn with a tiny tiny change.

Comment: Follows from the Akra–Bazzi theorem, which shows that all recurrences of this rough form have the same solution.